# Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 1

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

"DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-example- Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 1."

I know there are a lot of similar answers available on google, but most of them uses JSON and well, I don't. I know parameter '0' is referring to the event ID, can anyone enlighten me on where to change?

I have a class named "TrialEvent", a servlet named "EventRetrieveServlet" and Session Bean.

The below are the codes in my jsp.

```
<form method="get" action="EventRetrieveServlet">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                                    id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Event Ref.</th>
                                            <th>Image</th>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Start</th>
                                            <th>End</th>
                                            <th>Target Percentage (%)</th>
                                            <th>View Coordinate</th>

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <c:forEach var="rEvent" items="${eventList}" varStatus="i">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>${rEvent.getIdtrialevent()}</td>
                                                <td><img
                                                    src='displayImage?image=${rEvent.getTrialImage().getImageURL()}'
                                                    height=80px, width=100px></td>
                                                <td>${rEvent.getDate()}</td>
                                                <td>${rEvent.getStart()}</td>
                                                <td>${rEvent.getEnd()}</td>
                                                <td>${rEvent.getTargetperc()}</td>
                                                <td><a href="javascript:void(0)"
                                                    onclick="ShowNewPage(${rEvent.getAreacoords().getCoordsID()})"><img
                                                        src="assets/img/view.png" height=20px width=20px></a></td>
                                            <tr>
                                        </c:forEach>

                                    </tbody>

                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Here's my javascript

```
<!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Tables - Use for reference -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example').dataTable(
                );
    });
</script>
```

I'm trying to get paging to work, but i suspect this error is preventing the paging from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing correctly the `<tr>` tag before `</c:forEach>`.